# "a reduction in X" vs "a reduced X"

Tags: grammar

It seems that two different structures are used to indicate that one event causes a reduction/increase in something else.

> (1-a) This lifestyle might lead to a reduced blood pressure.
> (1-b) This lifestyle might lead to a reduction in blood pressure.
>
> (2-a) The changes in agricultural production are believed to be due to
> reduced oil prices.
> (2-b) The changes in agricultural production are believed to be due to a decrease in oil price.

I personally feel that(1-b) and (2-b) are more straightfoward than the other opition but (1-a) and (2-a) seem to be equally common.

Is there any difference between the two structures in terms of nuances and register?

Thank you.

Comment: (2.a) *due to* **reduced** *oil prices* and (2.b) *due to an* **increase** *in oil price* are very different.

Comment: You wouldn't say "a reduced blood pressure". Eliminate the indefinite article: "might lead to reduced blood pressure". In fact, I think I've always heard it (informally) stated "might lead to lower blood pressure".

Comment: And if this is supposed to be an academic/scholarly paper, "might lead" is a worthless statement. Find a sharper way to say the same thing, such as "is correlated with" or "has been shown to result in", etc. Of course, back up those statements with the proper references.

Comment: @Mari-LouA This question popped up on ELU's Top Questions page (top question on the page). As the OP was last seen on 15 September 2015 and with very little activity before then, they may not be coming back to address this. So I'm taking the initiative to change *an increase in oil price* to *a decrease in oil price* to match the rest of the question. If the OP or anyone else disagrees with this edit, please feel free to roll back the change.

Comment: _a **reduction** in oil production has not yielded to **reduced** oil prices, in fact this has increased oil prices._

Comment: 3kstc I suspect '...yielded to reduced...' is a typo, I think you mean '...led to reduced...' or '...resulted in reduced...'

Answer (score 1):

- *(1-a) This lifestyle might lead to a reduced **blood pressure**.*
- *(1-b) This lifestyle might lead to a **reduction** in blood pressure.*

I've emphasized the difference.

- The first sentence talks about the resulting **blood pressure**.
- The second sentence talks about the **change** in blood pressure - the fact that it is reduced (not increased) and the amount of reduction.

*Original thing minus reduction of thing = reduced thing.*

You have $5. I take $1 from you. The amount you have left, $4, is your reduced *wealth*. The amount you lost, $1, is the *reduction* in your wealth.

Which way of talking about the fact that your wealth has been reduced is "better"/"clearer"/...? That depends on what you really want to say/emphasize. In the abstract there is no best answer.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your basic question, there's not much difference between “a reduction in X” and “a reduced X.”  For example

> Such-and-so country flooded the market with cheap ______ (name of
>   product), resulting in reduced domestic prices, reduced profit margins, and
>   the closure of many local producers.

Or

> resulting in a reduction of domestic prices and profit margins.

Note 1: "due to an increase in oil price" should be *the price of oil*.

Note 2: A change in lifestyle can help alleviate a health condition known as "high blood pressure."  I suppose a lifestyle in which a very thin person tends to skip meals might result in frequent episodes of low blood pressure.  But without some context, your 1a and 1b don't make much sense.  Lifestyle changes take a long time to take effect, but blood pressure varies throughout the day as the person engages in exercise, ingests and digests food, etc.

Also I want to mention another possible resource for you, in case you don't know about it yet: https://ell.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

No.

You don’t need the ‘a’ in your first alternative 1a, which, like 2a, is then better than 1b (and 2b) because it is one word rather than three.

However, I would consider whether there is a more natural adjective that you could use — rather than one derived from a verb. In this case ‘lower’ would fit the bill. Just because it is a technical sentence, doesn’t mean you can’t use plain English.

If you strive for scientific precision, then use ‘decrease’, which has a clear opposite in ‘increase’, unlike the situation with ‘reduction’ (for which, as a biochemist, the opposite is ‘oxidation’). At all costs avoid ‘elegant variation’.